# Why have I diffrent timezone offset result in Oracle DB and in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timezone, offset

I have the following code to compare timezone offset of 'Asia/Novosibirsk' timezone in Oracle Database 11g (11.2.0.4.0) and in Java:

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;


public class TZTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            OracleDataSource oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            oracleDataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@some_host/some_sid");
            oracleDataSource.setUser("some_user");
            oracleDataSource.setPassword("some_passowrd");

            try (Connection connection = oracleDataSource.getConnection();
                 Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                 ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                         "SELECT TZ_OFFSET(sessiontimezone) tzo, sessiontimezone tzn FROM dual")
            ) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(
                            String.format("From DB:   %s %s",
                                    resultSet.getString("tzn"),
                                    resultSet.getString("tzo"))
                    );
                }
            }

            ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = now.atZone(zoneId);
            ZoneOffset offset = zonedDateTime.getOffset();

            String out = String.format("From Java: %s %s", zoneId, offset);
            System.out.println(out);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get that result :

```
From DB:   Asia/Novosibirsk +07:00 
From Java: Asia/Novosibirsk +06:00
```

**Why the offsets of this timezone is different ?**

I use this driver and this java version

```
ojdbc6.jar  (version 11.2.0.3.0 )
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation   
java.version: 1.8.0_40           
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2015a
```

Comment: It seems that the database returns the daylight saving time (DST).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here

[Link 1](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/novosibirsk) and [Link 2](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/luhansk-donetsk-moscow-time.html).

According to these links, there was a timezone shift happened to this area on 26th Oct 2014, which was taken into account by Java, but not by Oracle DB in your version.

Hopefully, they would have corrected it in the latest one.

Comment: do you think the problem in Oracle DB 11g (11.2.0.4.0) ?

Comment: I don't know about any specific version. This is my understanding based on the information I got while searching.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but might be the server which hosts your database and the one in which your java code runs are in different data centers which are in different timezones.

Try to find out the server locations for both of them and check if you can find something.

Comment: I was about to say the same. Make sure both you Java server and Oracle server are setup as being the same timezone.

Comment: If those servers would have different timezone, they would have returned the different timezone also, not just the different offset.

Comment: The offset is relative to UTC both in Oracle and in Java, so the host's timezone does not influence the result.

Comment: @kalyan-chavali  I have query in database 
"select dbtimezone from dual;" and it returns '+6:00'